# 1C 8.3. Что означает данная строка кода?

Tags: 1с

Есть такая строка кода:

```
Рез=ОбработкаРеквизита("СкидкаНаценкаРаботы",ТекСтрока,ЭтаФорма,ДопПараметры) И Рез;
```

Почему здесь стоит `И`?

Comment: Языка `1С` не знаю, но логично предположить, что это "логическое И". Таким образом удобно проверять несколько условий, что все они истинны. Вместо чтобы писать одну большую строку с множеством условий, можно в отдельных строках так `И` делать с текущим значением переменной и очередным условием. Ну, я предполагаю, что таков замысел.

Answer (score 0):

Можно предположить что в данном случае выполняется изменение Рез

```
Рез = ЗначениеФункции_ОбработкаРеквизита() И Рез;
// ЗначениеФункции_ОбработкаРеквизита() - функция возвращает: Истина / Ложь
```